# Grouping the tables in the database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've created a database with lots of tables in it and its difficult to manage them all, so is there any way to group certain tables into one folder in `phpmyadmin`?

Comment: Maybe it's a poor design

Comment: Hi Ashutosh. There are many ways to deal with large Databases. In some cases you may want to have multiple Databases with different tables for different parts of your application. You can also most of the time rethink you tables and probably reduce the amount you use. Give us a bit more information so we can give you a better awnser to you question.

Comment: i'm new to this, yeah, maybe it's a poor design. @Strawberry can you please suggest me some online tutorials or some other materials to improve myself in database designing ?

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with @Eli that you might be able to rework your structure to reduce the number of tables, there are a couple of ways to accomplish this (or, at least, get you closer).

First, there's actually a grouping feature that groups databases and tables. By default, it groups databases that start with the same prefix followed by an underscore, and tables that start with the same prefix and have a double underscore. For instance, databases named `mary_wordpress` and `mary_gallery2` would be grouped together under a `mary` header; likewise tables named `client__id`, `client__emails`, and `client__phone` would group together as `client` with the individual tables listed under that heading. Both of those separator values can be customized, see the configuration directives [`$cfg['NavigationTreeDbSeparator']`](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_NavigationTreeDbSeparator) and [`$cfg['NavigationTreeTableSeparator']`](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_NavigationTreeTableSeparator).

Furthermore, you can hide infrequently used tables or databases from the navigation pane. There's an icon to the right of the identifier (which looks like an eye in the default theme), by clicking that you can select to hide the database, table, view, routine, or other items from the navigation pane. You'll have to have a properly configured "phpMyAdmin configuration storage" in order for this to work, but many of the more advanced features require this and recently there's a zero configuration installation available which helps (I still recommend the old fashioned way explained in the manual, but the zeroconf works pretty well). Some more information about configuring the hiding feature is [in the manual](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_navigationhiding).

Finally, you can also use Favorites. This again [requires the configuration storage](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_favorite), but from a database structure tab you can click the star at the beginning of the "Action" row for a particular table to add it to your favorites, which will then appear in the dropdown at the top of your navigation pane.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name;